# AutoHotKey Text Shortcuts

Tags: autohotkey

SO I've done one line shortcuts but I'm curious how I would create a multi-line text shortcut.

```
^End::SendInput {Raw}My favorite Links for newbies:
```

This is what I currently use. By pressing CTRL+END it will paste the text. The problem is that I need list the links below on each succeeding line. I'm not sure how I would grasp then following lines.

```
^End::SendInput {Raw}My favorite Links for newbies:
1. Link1
2. Link2
3. Link3
.
.
.
```

Comment: `SendInput Line1\`nLine2\`nLine3`

Answer (score 2):

type {enter} where the new lines should be:

^End::SendInput My favorite Links for newbies: {enter}1. Link1{enter}2. Link2{enter}3. Link3

And I don't think it will work with 'raw'

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new line character `` `n `` in your string, but for readability I use a combination of parentheses which allow for multiple lines and `ltrim` which omits indentation from being included in the string.  Below is how I would do it:

```
^End::
     SendInput, 
        (ltrim 
            My favorite Links for newbies:
            1. Link1
            2. Link2
            3. Link3
        )
```